# UnicodeDecodeError while loading file in python

Tags: python, character-encoding, environment

I'm running this:

```
news_train = load_mlcomp('20news-18828', 'train')
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(encoding='latin1')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform((open(f, errors='ignore').read()
                                for f in news_train.filenames))
```

but it got UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 39: invalid continuation byte. at open() function.

I checked the news_train.filenames. It is:

```
array(['/Users/juby/Downloads/mlcomp/379/train/sci.med/12836-58920',
       ..., '/Users/juby/Downloads/mlcomp/379/train/sci.space/14129-61228'], 
      dtype='<U74')
```

Paths look correct. It may be about dtype or my environment (I'm Mac OSX 10.11), but I can't fix it after I tried many times. Thank you!!!

p.s it's a ML tutorial from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/mlcomp_sparse_document_classification.html#example-text-mlcomp-sparse-document-classification-py

Comment: Python 3? Try `open(f, mode='rb', errors='ignore')`.

Comment: Yes, it is Python3.5. I did it, but i got "binary mode doesn't take an errors argument"

Comment: Just remove the errors='ignore' can do the trick. Or the answer you posted yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the solution. Using

```
open(f, encoding = "latin1")
```

I'm not sure why it only happens on my mac though. Wish to know it.

Comment: When using text mode with `open` with Python 3, your locale is used to determine which encoding to decode the file. On Windows, that will be an 8-bit codepage like, latin1. On Mac and modern Linux, it's likely to be UTF-8. You should never `open` a file without specifying the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Python 3+, the `open` function opens and reads file in default mode `'r'` which will decode the file content (on most platform, in UTF-8). Since your files are encoded in latin1, decode them using UTF-8 could cause `UnicodeDecodeError`. The solution is either opening the files in binary mode (`'rb'`), or specify the correct encoding (`encoding="latin1"`).

```
open(f, 'rb').read()  # returns `byte` rather than `str`
# or,
open(f, encoding='latin1').read()  # returns latin1 decoded `str`
```